# Layer Syling icons and font size QGIS 3.8.3 64 Bit

Tags: qgis-3, font, icon

I've installed the 64 bit version of QGIS 3.8.3
I use an external full HD screen. Layer styling fonts and icons are extremely big. I've changed the font and icon size in options, but the problem persists.
Is there a solution to this?

[image]

Attached is a picture of the issue.

Comment: Please comment on if you have the same problem when you view the data in a print layout. Does the problem persist?

Comment: My problem is basically with the interface of the layer styling. Fonts and icons are huge! Compare the size of the fonts in there with the icon size on the top of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a bug. All user interface parts of QGIS should behave in the same way. So where the other menus, panels etc respond to the resolution on your screen it would seem this is not the case for this panel. I suggest you search through the QGIS list of bugs and file a new one if it has not already been filed.

Answer (score 2):

To control the size of your label fonts make sure you use millimeters and not points. Experiment with them unless you do not immediately succeed. Your options are:

- Millimeter
- Points
- Pixels
- Meters at scale
- Map units
- Inches

This is something you set in the layer properties:

[image]

Similarly the size unit can be set for the symbols you are using.

The following factors also have implications on the way your fonts are presented:

- On the bottom of the map canvas there is a "Magnifier" option. It is usually set to 100%. Make sure this is the case.
- Shifting between screen resolutions (plugging in external monitors) can mess up the way Windows renders fonts and more. Make sure your screen resolution and the rendering is adjusted accordingly.
- Combining two different screens (laptop screen and external) can add to the confusion.
- External screen driver can have implications. I guess generic drivers could misinterpret screen dots per inch (dpi).
- Graphics card controllers like NVIDIA can also have a say in the rendering. So consult the settings there as well if the above does not help.

Comment: Thanks. I think I didn't make myself clear. My problem is with the Layer Styling Panel and other panels, not the canvas. Look at size of it... the fonts the buttons, everything is huge.  Sometimes I have to drag the layer styling panel to almost the middle of the screen to see all buttons. The buttons on the toolbars are ok, but fonts and buttons on panels are extremely big.

Comment: I would then consider this something of a bug. All user interface parts of QGIS should behave in the same way. So where the other menus, panels etc respond to the resolution on your screen it would seem this is not the case for this panel. I suggest you search through the QGIS list of bugs and file a new one if it has not already been filed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind answer. I will check the bugs list.

Comment: @AndresAristizabal I have added another answer to your question. I am keeping my initial answer as it indicates the complexities of working with sizes of objects in QGIS. I suggest you accept the answer indicating a bug if you agree this is the cease.